# Recorrer cada indice del array indexado, y de cada indice extraer el user preestablecido con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, login

Buenas! Es mi primer año estudiando javascript, tengo una tarea de la cual necesito hacer una especie de paginas de pedidos, para facilitarnos las cosas, el profesor nos pidió añadir usuarios directamente a los clientes y a los funcionarios (dos tipos de usuarios) en arrays asociativos y crear dos arrays indexados para guardar a los clientes y los funcionarios en cada una.

Preciso saber como recorrer cada indice del array indexado, y de cada indice (que sería un array asociativo) extraer el user preestablecido con JQuery.

Este es mi JS hasta el momento

```js
var arregloClientes=[]; //array indexado de clientes
var arregloFuncionarios=[]; //array indexado de funcionarios
var cliente1={}; //array asociativo de cada cliente
var cliente2={};
var cliente3={};
var cliente4={};
var funcionario1={}; //array asociativo de cada funcionario
var funcionario2={};
var funcionario3={};
var funcionario4={};

cliente1.numero=1; //número asigando a cada cliente
cliente1.nombre="Juan"; //nombre del cliente
cliente1.apellido="Pérez"; //apellido del cliente
cliente1.usuario="JuP"; //nick del cliente
cliente1.contraseña="123456"; //contraseña del cliente
cliente1.direccion="Uruguay 198"; //dirección de cada cliente
cliente1.telefono="099 987 432"; //teléfono de cada cliente
arregloClientes.push(cliente1); //agregar el cliente al arreglo donde se los contiene

cliente2.numero=2;
cliente2.nombre="Alison";
cliente2.apellido="Normas";
cliente2.usuario="AliNM";
cliente2.contraseña="159753";
cliente2.direccion="Las Piedras 554";
cliente2.telefono="099 123 654";
arregloClientes.push(cliente2);

cliente3.numero=3;
cliente3.nombre="Carlos";
cliente3.apellido="Pérez";
cliente3.usuario="CarlyP";
cliente3.contraseña="123456789";
cliente3.direccion="Uruguay 698";
cliente3.telefono="094 781 898";
arregloClientes.push(cliente3);

cliente4.numero=4;
cliente4.nombre="Mónica";
cliente4.apellido="Rattin";
cliente4.usuario="MoniRT";
cliente4.contraseña="14789632";
cliente4.direccion="Artigas 850";
cliente4.telefono="098 149 716";
arregloClientes.push(cliente4);

funcionario1.numero=1;  //número de cada funcionario
funcionario1.nombre="Mercedes"; //nombre de cada funcionario
funcionario1.apellido="Dos Santos"; //apellido de cada funcionario
funcionario1.cedula="4.789.564-4"; //cédula de cada funcionario
funcionario1.usuario="MecheDS"; //usuario de cada funcionario
funcionario1.contraseña="meche123"; //contraseña de cada funcionario
arregloFuncionarios.push(funcionario1); //agrega al funcionario al arreglo que los contiene

funcionario2.numero=2;
funcionario2.nombre="Julio";
funcionario2.apellido="Machado";
funcionario2.cedula="4.712.697-7";
funcionario2.usuario="JulioM";
funcionario2.contraseña="julio14";
arregloFuncionarios.push(funcionario2);

funcionario3.numero=3
funcionario3.nombre="Agustín";
funcionario3.apellido="Conde";
funcionario3.cedula="5.462.169-9";
funcionario3.usuario="AguCD";
funcionario3.contraseña="agustin321";
arregloFuncionarios.push(funcionario3);

funcionario4.numero=4;
funcionario4.nombre="Andrea";
funcionario4.apellido="Da Rosa";
funcionario4.cedula="5.236.368-8";
funcionario4.usuario="AndreDR";
funcionario4.contraseña="andreita456";
arregloFuncionarios.push(funcionario4);
```

Comment: Por favor podrias cambiar el titulo de la pregunta y poner algo mas descriptivo como `encontrar un objeto en un array por un key`, pues el problema de loguearse no es precisamente el que se aborda en la pregunta, y `necesito ayuda` tampoco deberia aparecer en el titulo

Answer (score 1):

Deberías utilizar la función [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach). Es la encargada de recorrer un array y te permite trabajar con cada uno de los objetos:

```js
var arregloClientes=[]; //array indexado de clientes
var arregloFuncionarios=[]; //array indexado de funcionarios
var cliente1={}; //array asociativo de cada cliente
var cliente2={};
var cliente3={};
var cliente4={};
var funcionario1={}; //array asociativo de cada funcionario
var funcionario2={};
var funcionario3={};
var funcionario4={};

cliente1.numero=2; //número asigando a cada cliente
cliente1.nombre="Juan"; //nombre del cliente
cliente1.apellido="Pérez"; //apellido del cliente
cliente1.usuario="JuP"; //nick del cliente
cliente1.contraseña="123456"; //contraseña del cliente
cliente1.direccion="Uruguay 198"; //dirección de cada cliente
cliente1.telefono="099 987 432"; //teléfono de cada cliente
arregloClientes.push(cliente1); //agregar el cliente al arreglo donde se los contiene

cliente2.numero=1;
cliente2.nombre="Alison";
cliente2.apellido="Normas";
cliente2.usuario="AliNM";
cliente2.contraseña="159753";
cliente2.direccion="Las Piedras 554";
cliente2.telefono="099 123 654";
arregloClientes.push(cliente2);

cliente3.numero=3;
cliente3.nombre="Carlos";
cliente3.apellido="Pérez";
cliente3.usuario="CarlyP";
cliente3.contraseña="123456789";
cliente3.direccion="Uruguay 698";
cliente3.telefono="094 781 898";
arregloClientes.push(cliente3);

cliente4.numero=4;
cliente4.nombre="Mónica";
cliente4.apellido="Rattin";
cliente4.usuario="MoniRT";
cliente4.contraseña="14789632";
cliente4.direccion="Artigas 850";
cliente4.telefono="098 149 716";
arregloClientes.push(cliente4);

funcionario1.numero=1;  //número de cada funcionario
funcionario1.nombre="Mercedes"; //nombre de cada funcionario
funcionario1.apellido="Dos Santos"; //apellido de cada funcionario
funcionario1.cedula="4.789.564-4"; //cédula de cada funcionario
funcionario1.usuario="MecheDS"; //usuario de cada funcionario
funcionario1.contraseña="meche123"; //contraseña de cada funcionario
arregloFuncionarios.push(funcionario1); //agrega al funcionario al arreglo que los contiene

funcionario2.numero=2;
funcionario2.nombre="Julio";
funcionario2.apellido="Machado";
funcionario2.cedula="4.712.697-7";
funcionario2.usuario="JulioM";
funcionario2.contraseña="julio14";
arregloFuncionarios.push(funcionario2);

funcionario3.numero=3
funcionario3.nombre="Agustín";
funcionario3.apellido="Conde";
funcionario3.cedula="5.462.169-9";
funcionario3.usuario="AguCD";
funcionario3.contraseña="agustin321";
arregloFuncionarios.push(funcionario3);

funcionario4.numero=4;
funcionario4.nombre="Andrea";
funcionario4.apellido="Da Rosa";
funcionario4.cedula="5.236.368-8";
funcionario4.usuario="AndreDR";
funcionario4.contraseña="andreita456";
arregloFuncionarios.push(funcionario4);


  function muestraFuncionarios()
    {
     arregloFuncionarios.sort(function(a, b) {
       return a.numero - b.numero;
     });
      arregloFuncionarios.forEach(function(item, index)
      {
        console.log("FUNCIONARIO: "+item.nombre);
      });
    }
    
    function muestraClientes()
    {
        arregloClientes.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a.numero - b.numero;
        });
        arregloClientes.forEach(function(item, index){
          console.log("CLIENTE: "+item.nombre);
        });
    }
    muestraFuncionarios();
    muestraClientes();
```

**EDITADO:**

> Leyendo tu pregunta mejor, veo que quizá quieres leer el array por el
>   orden del número (es decir el número indexado). Esto tendrías que
>   hacerlo transformando antes de hacer los `forEach` con
>   [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort). He cambiado el orden de Alison por el de Juan

Comment: te recomiendo que cambies: `alert` por `console.log`

Comment: No sabía que ahora salía la consola debajo!! es genial!!! mil gracias!

Comment: Muchas gracias! No sabía donde responder porque soy nuevo en el foro por eso te agradezco ahora!

Comment: De nada!! Si finalmente fue la solución márcala como respuesta correcta para dejar la pregunta resuelta !! Gracias !!

Answer (score 0):

Hay que aclarar que los arrays asociativos (o diccionarios) no existen en javascript, muchos caen en el error pensando que estan creando un array asociatido cuando realmente estan creando objetos y añadiendo propiedades dinamicamente.

Como no existen los arrays asociativos no podemos recorrerlos con un for o un foreach, ordenarlos u obtener un length de los elementos que contiende.

Sin embargo con un for..in podemos recorrer las prpiedades de cualquier objeto

```
for (variable in objeto){sentencias}
```

Veamos como recorrer las propiedades de los objetos de tu ejemplo (solo lo hice para los clientes, para funcionarios seria lo mismo)

```js
var arregloClientes=[]; //array indexado de clientes
var cliente1={}; //array asociativo de cada cliente
var cliente2={};
var cliente3={};
var cliente4={};

cliente1.numero=1; //número asigando a cada cliente
cliente1.nombre="Juan"; //nombre del cliente
cliente1.apellido="Pérez"; //apellido del cliente
cliente1.usuario="JuP"; //nick del cliente
cliente1.contraseña="123456"; //contraseña del cliente
cliente1.direccion="Uruguay 198"; //dirección de cada cliente
cliente1.telefono="099 987 432"; //teléfono de cada cliente
arregloClientes.push(cliente1); //agregar el cliente al arreglo donde se los contiene

cliente2.numero=2;
cliente2.nombre="Alison";
cliente2.apellido="Normas";
cliente2.usuario="AliNM";
cliente2.contraseña="159753";
cliente2.direccion="Las Piedras 554";
cliente2.telefono="099 123 654";
arregloClientes.push(cliente2);

cliente3.numero=3;
cliente3.nombre="Carlos";
cliente3.apellido="Pérez";
cliente3.usuario="CarlyP";
cliente3.contraseña="123456789";
cliente3.direccion="Uruguay 698";
cliente3.telefono="094 781 898";
arregloClientes.push(cliente3);

cliente4.numero=4;
cliente4.nombre="Mónica";
cliente4.apellido="Rattin";
cliente4.usuario="MoniRT";
cliente4.contraseña="14789632";
cliente4.direccion="Artigas 850";
cliente4.telefono="098 149 716";
arregloClientes.push(cliente4);

console.log("Clientes");

for(var i=0; i<arregloClientes.length; i++){
 console.log("----- Cliente " + (i+1) );
 for(var propiedad in arregloClientes[i]){
     console.log(propiedad+" = ",arregloClientes[i][propiedad]);
 }
 console.log("-----");
}
```